# How to specify a minimum count on an association using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Battle class which has many Participants.  I'm using this class method to return the last Battle to be voted on:

```
def self.get_voteable_battle
  #return the battle whose submissions_deadline ended less than 3 days ago
  time_now = Time.now
  end_of_day = time_now.end_of_day
  return self.where(:submissions_deadline => end_of_day.ago(3.days)..time_now).first
end
```

But I also want to ensure that there are at least 2 participants.

I can add another condition like this:

```
def self.get_voteable_battle
  #return the battle whose submissions_deadline ended less than 3 days ago
  time_now = Time.now
  end_of_day = time_now.end_of_day
  battle = self.where(:submissions_deadline => end_of_day.ago(3.days)..time_now).first
  if battle && battle.participants.count > 1
    return battle
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

But this would require another query right?  Is there a way to do it in one query using active record?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
self.joins(:participants).where(:submissions_deadline => end_of_day.ago(3.days)..time_now).having('count(participants.id) > ?', 1).last
```

It may be the battle id in the `having` clause but one of the two will work and i'll update. head hurts right now.